# Does offload app count as "Uninstall" App Store Connect dashboard?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, firebase-analytics

I am confused with Apple definition of "Uninstall" in App Store Connect Dashboard and offload feature of iOS 11. Does app being offload count as being uninstalled and un-offload count as install. Or is there exception or special circumstance.

Also for bonus, how does Firebase Analytic handle this case?

Comment: An offloaded app is still installed